# Figure numbering by section

Tags: floats, numbering

I have several figures and at the moment the figure numbers correspond with section they are in but I want the figures to be numbered continuously. Here is a part of my code. i hope you can help me:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{bi-arch}
    \caption{Architecture }
    \label{fig:arch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{figure}{section}` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. In standard `article` document class figures are numbered continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this at the beginning of your code:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
```

Hope it helps!